# How to write a specific dict comprehension?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I got this question at an interview and I did not know how to solve it then and I am trying to solve it now.

If I have two lists:

```
l1 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
l2 = [0, 2, 4, 8, 10]
```

how can I write a dict comprehension that will produce `{1:0, 3:2, 5:4, 7:8, 9:10}`?

Comment: `{first: second for first, second in zip(l1, l2)}`

Comment: Or you can make it even short by `dict(zip(l1, l2))`

Answer (score 2):

```
l1 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
l2 = [0, 2, 4, 8, 10]
dict(zip(l1, l2))
```

output:

```
{1: 0, 3: 2, 5: 4, 7: 8, 9: 10}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `zip` built-in function to combine multiple lists into an iterable of tuples. This `zip` iterable can be made into a dictionary.

#### Syntax

```
for (valueoflist1,valueoflist2) in zip(list1,list2):
   #Code
```

#### Code resolution:

```
result = {key: val for key ,val in zip(keys ,values)}
```

or

```py
    result = dict(zip(keys, values))
```

Comment: You should avoid using `dict` as a variable name.

Comment: i know, i'll fix that bad habit someday

Comment: Note: There is no need for the parentheses around the names to be unpacked, and it's slightly better style to omit them (and include spaces after the `:` and `,`), e.g. `{vl1: vl2 for vl1, vl2 in zip(lst1, lst2)}`